# Laravel scoping a sync possible?

Tags: php, laravel

I swear it was possible to do something like this

```
$user->roles()->where('role_column', 'value')->sync( array( 1, 2, 3 ) );
```

So that I can sync relationships and only affect relationships that fit the query. Essentially using the query to compare ids, and only detaching those not in the given array if they match the query are found by the query.

Is this not possible?

I am aware that pivot queries do achieve this, so maybe I got mixed up. That isn't what I need.

Thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations it only works for many to many relationships and I don't think you can add any filtering. I'm not sure I understand the desired result here? You want user to only be associated with roles 1,2 and 3 but how is the other condition coming into play?

Comment: Technically im using a morphToMany, but it also has sync. The other conditions come into play, because the user has many roles attatched where 'role_column' does not equal 'value' as shown in the  example, but I don't want to detach those. Only want to detach the difference of the given ids etc

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I can find is

1 Querying all currently attached, getting those ids

2 Querying currently attached with my desired filters, getting those ids

3 Getting array of diff (ids from 1 that arent in 2)

4 Syncing my desired ids, merged with ids from 3